# Calculating Prime numbers using arrays

Tags: c, arrays, numbers

I am reading a book called programming in C by Stephen G. Kochan, Exercise 7 of chapter 7, I have only covered variables, data types, arithmetic expressions, program looping, decision making and working with arrays, nothing else.

This problem asks us to display the first 150 prime numbers using an algorithm called *Sieve of Erastosthenes* the steps of which are listed below
step 1: Define an array of integers P. Set all elements P[i] to 0, 2<= i <=n
step 2: set i to 2
step 3: if i > n, the algorithm terminates.
step 4: If P[i] is 0, then i is prime.
step 5: For all positive integer values of j, such that i*j <= n, set P[i*j] to 1
step 6: Add 1 to i and go to step 3.

I understood the algorithm but when I tried to implement it, it's just returning 0.

```
//Sieve of Erastosthenes

#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)

{
  int i, j, P[151];


  for (i = 2; i <= 150; ++i)
    P[i] = 0;

  for (i = 2; i <= 150; ++i ){

    if (P[i] = 0)
        printf ("%i ", P[i]);

    for (j = 1; j*i <= 150; ++j)
        P[i*j] = 1;

  }
    return 0;

}
```

Also, I know I have to include the header file  to use **bool** in my program, do I need to add anything to use **double**?

Comment: Related: ["You're gonna need a bigger boat"](http://www.ign.com/top/movie-moments/5) -  (or in your case, a bigger array). At best your code will only compute the primes below 150, not the first 150 primes, bugs not withstanding (which there are).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
if (P[i] = 0)
```

is not a test, it's an assignment (which of course results in a value that is tested by `if`, but the actual expression is not a test).

C has `=` for assignment and `==` for equality-testing. Enable more compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

The exercise is to list the prime numbers up to 150 (not the first 150 primes).

You are getting 0 for each answer because this code

```
if (P[i] = 0)
    printf ("%i ", P[i]);
```

should instead read

```
if ( P[i] == 0 )
     printf ("%i ", i);
```

You want to print i -- the loop index value -- not the value of array element P[i].